# How to solve `configure: error: Cannot find OpenSSL's <evp.h>`?

Tags: php, openssl

Im trying to recompile PHP, but ./configure fails at :

```
configure: error: Cannot find OpenSSL's <evp.h>
```

I have LibSSL 1.0.0, LibSSL 0.9.8, LibSSL-Dev, OpenSSL installed.

```
--with-openssl=/usr/include/openssl
```

when I try with

```
--with-openssl
```

tells me:

configure: error: Cannot find OpenSSL's libraries

Where the **** are the problem ?

P.S. Php is 5.2.5, OS is Ubuntu

Answer (score 50):

The same issue occurred on `Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS` and it was solved by issuing:

`sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev pkg-config`

Comment: Hello :) I forgot how do I solve my problem. :) It was a half year ago.

Comment: How is `libcurl4-openssl-dev` different from `libssl-dev`?

Answer (score 18):

To build php-5.3 on Debian wheezy you need the following to fix this error.

```
apt-get install libssl-dev libsslcommon2-dev
```

Then you need to configure with the following included

```
./configure --with-libdir=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu ...
```

Comment: 1+, helped me a lot. I also had to add `--with-php-config /usr/local/src/php-x.x.x/scripts/php_config`. I have written a [how-to compile PHP with extensions.](http://blog.flowl.info/2015/compile-php-5-6-pthreads-mongo-ubuntu/?utm_source=serverfault)

Comment: works but fails all test cases.

Comment: Works to for PHP5.2 manual compile on Ubuntu 14.04 with "--with-openssl" directive. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 13):

Assuming that you already have the OpenSSL libraries and header files (on rpm systems the latter are in the xxxx-devel package)...

The issue seems to arise from how `configure` resolves dependencies which are distributed around the filesystem. To compile the code, the comiler needs to know where the headers are. To link the code, the linker needs to know where the libraries are.

```
[colin@host]$ configure .... --with-openssl-dir=/usr/include/openssl ....
...
checking OpenSSL dir for FTP... /usr/include/openssl
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
configure: error: Cannot find OpenSSL's <evp.h>

[colin@host]$ find /usr/include -name evp.h
/usr/include/openssl/evp.h
```

The include directory has the include file, but pkg-config fails because the library is *not* in /usr/include/openssl, its in /usr/lib

Running configure again with /usr as the directory:

```
configure .... --with-openssl-dir=/usr ....
...
checking OpenSSL dir for FTP... /usr
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking for OpenSSL version... >= 0.9.6
checking for CRYPTO_free in -lcrypto... yes
...
```

The path passed as an argument is searched to find the relevant resources.

Comment: This worked for me. This is a good solution.

Comment: This was solution on debian wheezy + php 5.3.10! Thank you!!!!

Comment: @holms: that's now a rather old version of php. Particularly if you're going to use compiled-from-source rather than managed packages,  then you should use a recent release.

Comment: This was the solution for me building `php-7.1.12` on `Debian Jessie`. Thank you

Answer (score 11):

To compile php-5.4.45 on debian 8.1 (Jessie) i had to:

```
apt-get install libssl-dev
```

After that I could compile it just using `--with-openssl`

Answer (score 9):

Another reason `./configure` might fail is because you don't have `pkg-config` installed, like in my case with PHP7 and Debian Jessie:

```
sudo apt-get install pkg-config
```

Comment: That was already pointed out in a different answer from three years ago.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the issue by installing extra libraries

```
sudo apt-get install -y autoconf g++ make openssl libssl-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev
sudo apt-get install -y libcurl4-openssl-dev pkg-config
sudo apt-get install -y libsasl2-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

On centos7  Install openssl-devel
`yum install openssl-devel`

Answer (score 0):

You need to help configure figuring out where to look for the evp.h file, because by default it will scan for directories and add hardcoded suffixes to them to find it. I've kept the details in [my wiki page](https://ychaouche.informatick.net/phpevp.h) for those who want to understand the solution. Here's what worked for me :

```
root@audio-mon[10.10.10.82] ~/DOWNLOADS/php-5.5.23/ext/mysqlnd # PHP_OPENSSL_DIR="/usr /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"
root@audio-mon[10.10.10.82] ~/DOWNLOADS/php-5.5.23/ext/mysqlnd # ./configure --with-libdir=""
[...]
checking for DSA_get_default_method in -lssl... yes
checking for X509_free in -lcrypto... yes
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking for OpenSSL version... >= 0.9.6 #                     <------------------------------------- YES !
[...]
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
root@audio-mon[10.10.10.82] ~/DOWNLOADS/php-5.5.23/ext/mysqlnd #
```

YMMV (paths are different). If that didn't work for you [check the wiki page](https://ychaouche.informatick.net/phpevp.h), it will help you figure out what paths to put.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Fedora 19 despite having OpenSSL installed.

I had to install openssl-devel.i686 which I found by doing a generic search for all packages related to ssl:

```
sudo yum search ssl
sudo yum install openssl-devel.i686
```

Then I ran configure again with success:

```
sudo ./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs --with-mysql --enable-mbstring --with-mysqli --with-openssl=/usr/
```

Answer (score 0):

Just my feedback: After solving this ssl problem from thsi post, I've completely give up on compiling php 5.3 because it's failed down futher on zend dom extensions in the middle, I've found some patches, and decided just to drop this fuss. There's ubuntu 12.04 which still has 5.3.10 php on board. Be careful php-fpm back then been clearing environment variables. So don't be surprised when you can't pass global variables from docker for example.